What's the maximum size limit for an Earthlike shellworld?
While the title does look similar to this one, it's actually not.
For anyone not in the know, a shellworld is a popular sci-fi megastructure in which a hollow shell envelops a planet, a star or--in the case of birchworlds--a black hole.
In this scenario, there are nine layers to this shellworld, representing the actual layers of the Earth, from top to bottom:

Continental crust
Oceanic crust
Uppermost mantle
Partially molten asthenosphere
Solid asthenosphere
Mantle transition
Lower mantle
Outer core
Inner core

It's got a gravity, climate and atmosphere very similar to Earth, as well as all the things that make Earth such a dynamically interesting planet--situation within a star's habitable zone, axial tilt, lunar stability, plate tectonics, continents, oceans, magnetic fields, you name it.  However, there comes a point where conditions on the surface are no longer Earthlike and instead unacceptable for Earth colonists.  What's the maximum size limit, in regards to diameter, for a shellworld to be basically a scaled-up Earth?

The shell theorem states gravity inside a spherical shell is zero, the gravity due to the mass under your feet balanced by the gravity above your head. That means all that's keeping one on the ground is centripetal force. But that force works on the entire shell, not just the people living on the interior surface... that would suggest the energy required to keep the thickness of the shell intact is at odds with the centripetal force. Add to this the unusually close proximity of a sun to duplicate the hot core of the Earth and that should do it - but I don't have the skill to give you a number.

@JBH, the gravity of the outside of a shell within a bigger shell would be that of the outside of the contained shell alone, as the inside of any shell of uniformly distributed mass is 0g.

So a shell-world is a Dyson-sphere? (or several layers of Dyson spheres)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere

At least 700 times the radius of the Sun.
A red supergiant like Betelgeuse has a mass about 17 times that of the Sun, and a radius about 700 times the radius of the Sun.  As a result the surface gravity is milder than the Sun's 27.9 gees - something around a milligee, less than the Moon.  It will, of course, be hard to find enough planet building material to provide ordinary Earth gravity around the entire surface area of that star.
Betelgeuse has a temperature around 3700 K or 6200 Fahrenheit, which sounds a little warm, but to quote a Duke University press release on plasmonic carbides, "The new materials are hard enough to stir molten steel and can withstand temperatures above 7,000 degrees Fahrenheit". This permits you to build the "inner core" of your planet directly atop the star.  Of course, it is advisable to avoid leaks or your "ship" (the entire planet) will sink.
There are some long-term issues to deal with.  Stars like to shine, so roofing Betelgeuse over with cool farm fields raises a question of where the heat is going to go.  I'd suggest pair production of neutrinos from pure energy.  You need merely figure out a way to do this in large numbers, so that the neutrinos carry away so much thermal energy in their random motion that they replace radiative cooling by electromagnetism.  Neutron stars use this method of cooling naturally, but you'll need to come up with a catalyst.  Once you arrange this cooling, the core will remain safely supported by the chaotic plasmonic matter, and you'll be able to make ordinary heat engines to recover the energy you need to make the neutrinos.  (It's not a perpetual motion machine - it's just a star shining a different way)
Betelgeuse is also somewhat unstable.  Preventing mass loss by roofing it over will avoid one sort of change, but you'll still need to come up with some way to stir the star to get more hydrogen into the core long term.  Fortunately you control its entire surface and can play with its internal magnetic fields however you wish.
I see some comments about the final gravity of the construct.  This depends largely on how realistic the Earth model needs to be.  If it is a literal planetary surface with a core and mantle comparable to Earth, then it will be quite a thick layer around the star.  By the shell theorem (who knew we would end up back there?) we can calculate the gravity simply by counting the mass as added to the star.  To my surprise, the Sun has the area of only 12,000 Earths, and if we take that times 700x700 we have 5.9e+9 more surface area.  Crudely multiplying that times Earth's mass of 6.0e+27 grams = 3.5e+37 g.  The Sun's mass is 2e+33 g, times 17 gets 3.4e+34 g for Betelgeuse's weight.  The good news is that a full Earth layer amps up Betelgeuse's gravity by a factor of 1000, bringing it to a normal Earth gee.  The bad news is that we can't rest that on the surface of Betelgeuse any more; we'll crush it like a beer can.  So, what are we going to do?  We can make compromises and start marketing our shell world as a light hearted paradise.  Or we can do some serious subway construction and outfit this world with a network of air-conditioned long distance haulers continually circumnavigating the world at nearly the speed of light, creating a huge centrifugal force that holds up the inner core, hence everything above it.  I'll let you guess which one I prefer, but it's up to you. :)

If a shellworld around Betelguese has a surface gravity of about a milligee it would very probably lead to heath problems for humans colonizing it.  Maybe they would build giant centrifuges for people to  periodically experience Earth like gravity, or maybe they would some sort of gravity generators.

And this escape velocity calculator says it would have an escape velocity of only 0.16682 kilometers per second.  https://www.calctool.org/astrophysics/escape-velocity  Its a good think that it will have shells to hold in the atmosphere.

I've made some edits above to address this.  But it is the builder's responsibility to source all construction materials. :)  Technically yes, this means by the time you finish building around the star, its role is mostly decorative.

@M.A.Golding  I wasn't building this for the humans.
